# How to connect two animations on one element with React Spring?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a button that will trigger every 2 seconds and change it's scale from 1 to 1.5 and have on the same element second animation but only when you put mouse over it. My problem is that I don't know how to connect this two `useSpring` hooks.

My animation on hover:

```
  const buttonAnimation = useSpring({
    backgroundColor: !isVisible ? '#4b1220' : '#fff',
  });
```

and I want to apply second animation

```
const buttonInfAnimation = useSpring({
    from: {
      scale: 1,
    },
    to: {
      scale: 1.5,
    },
  });
```

When I call this like this, I'm getting only latest animation in code:

```
<animated.button
  style={{...buttonInfAnimation, ...buttonAnimation}}
  onMouseLeave={() => setVisibility(false)}
  onMouseEnter={() => setVisibility(true)}
  className="hover"
></animated.button>
```

How to apply two animations with React Springs on one element? I have tried to implement `useSprings` but I don't understand it correctly how to use this.
https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-springs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create two separate spring animation. You can combine them. And for the scale you have to use the transform css property.

```js
const buttonInfAnimation = useSpring({
  from: {
    transform: 'scale(1)',
  },
  to: {
    transform: 'scale(1.5)',
    backgroundColor: !isVisible ? '#4b1220' : '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: I was asking about: One animation on Hover and second animation on click, two different listeners

Comment: I understand the question, but it works in just one animation all the same. https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-2jurp